# change solaris ip address using a script

Tags: unix, scripting, solaris

I have always changed Solaris 10 ip address using the classic method by modifying /etc/inet/hosts and /etc/inet/inodes.

Is there a way to change the ip address using scripting??

Comment: Write a script to edit the files in question?

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/inet/ipnodes` (not inodes) should be a symbolic link pointing to `/etc/inet/hosts`, at least on recent Solaris 10 updates. You might anyway just directly access the `/etc/hosts` file but this is not what I would recommend unless you are in single user mode. The reason why is an out of sync hosts file might trigger various problems and hangs depending on the services running on your machine.

You can dynamically change the IP address using the [ifconfig](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5166/ifconfig-1m/index.html) command and that is actually the only way to do it (using the CLI).

Another way to change the address that will be picked at reboot is to directly put it in the `/etc/hostname.<interface>` file(s). This is the supported and documented way.

Note that with Solaris 11, [ipadm](https://blogs.oracle.com/observatory/entry/ipadm) has replaced ifconfig and unlike the latter, allows persistent configuration, i.e you can change your IP address in a simple script that doesn't involves editing a configuration file.

Comment: ifconfig does not change the address permanently. And as I said I always add the address directly to the /hosts file and I thought there'd be a script that can update the address automatically within hosts file without using vi editor or something else. Thanks anyway

Comment: ifconfig is the only CLI way to change the IP address under Solaris 10. When you modify the host IP address the /etc/host file, nothing happens with the effective IP address. However, you might break applications running. It is recommended to modify instead the /etc/hostname.<interface> content instead. When you reboot, these changes are picked-up and ifconfig is used internally to configure the network interface.